# Performance bottlenecks in Paillier encryption

Tags: implementation, paillier

I'm implementing Paillier encryption and I'd like some recommendations about improving its performance.

Firstly, I have to note the following:

- I have already set g=1+n to get rid of one exponentiation.
- I've been using the CRT to improve decryption.

Nevertheless, the computation of r^n mod n^2 is rather intensive, do you have any other trick to improve the performance?

Note: I don't want to use the Catalano et al. improvement with e as I want to keep its homomorphic property intact.

Comment: Just wanted to add [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/864.pdf) as a reference for future readers.

Comment: A CRT method giving improvement by a factor approaching 4 (for standard multiplication algorithms) is described in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/106605/555). I know no further improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that in Paillier encryption with public key $n$ of private factorization and $g=1+n$, encryption of plaintext $m$ reduces to:

- choose random $r$, $0<r<n$
- compute and output ciphertext $c=(1+n\cdot m)\cdot r^n\bmod n^2$.

Some ideas:

1. In some contexts, it is feasible to pre-compute $r^n\bmod n^2$ in masked time, before the encryption itself, meaning there is no modular exponentiation involved in encryption (only one multiplication and one modular multiplication); delay from plaintext-in to ciphertext-out is thus drastically reduced.
2. Using existing tightly optimized modular exponentiation code like in [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) might achieve 3, 4 and 5 below with little effort.
3. Tight coding (often, assembly) pays a lot for modular multiplication, and thus modular exponentiation (which is dominated by modular multiplication). Gaining a factor of 3 is common, 10 is not unseen if assembly coding allows to double the effective word width used for multiplication (e.g. C might not allows to use the full 128-bit result of a 64-bit times 64-bit multiplication available in hardware, or effective use of the carry bit).
4. Depending on hardware and size of $n$, it might pay to perform some optimizations that are not worthwhile for RSA and $n$ of comparable size, because the modulus width for modular multiplications is doubled in Paillier; even quadrupled (or more with multiprime-RSA) if the CRT is used and one compares the expensive operations, which are encryption in Paillier, and decryption in RSA. These optimizations include

- sub-quadratic multiplication, like [Karatsuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) and [friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fast_multiplication_algorithms_for_large_inputs);
- modular reduction by multiplication with pre-computed inverse;
- performing modular squaring by squaring with reuse of partial products (as in [Algorithm 14.16 in the HAC](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf#page=8)) followed by modular reduction.

5. Sliding Window exponentiation (see [Algorithm 14.85 in the HAC](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf#page=27)) will give some improvement (like -20%) over a standard exponent scanning, and slightly more so than in RSA.
6. [Update] Most important, but perhaps already in the question: for decryption (only), a CRT method giving improvement by a factor approaching 4 (for standard multiplication algorithms; 3 with Karastuba) is described in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/106605/555).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. For the time being I'm implementing this in MIRACL (www.certivox.com/miracl/) and I was thinking whether there is a trick for r^n mod n^2 analogous to the one for g that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @absinthe_minded: see new 6 and [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/106605/555).